# unsafe instance field in a record and record parameter

Tags: c#, record, c#-9.0

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records) it is said:

> Record parameters cannot use `ref`, `out` or `this` modifiers.

and:

> It is an error for an instance field of a record to have an unsafe type.

What is meant by "Record parameters" and "instance field"?

I tested the following program in Visual Studio 2019 and it has no errors:

```
using System;

unsafe record Record
{
    unsafe public int* p;
}
record Program
{
    unsafe static void f(out Record param)
    {
        int g = 1000;
        param = new Record { p = &g };
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        unsafe
        {
            Record r;
            f(out r);
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Isn't `p` an instance field? Isn't `param` a record parameter?

Comment: Are you sure your project .NET 5.0 and not an older version?

Comment: That code does not compile for me.

Comment: @Russ in older versions `record` is not usable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad probably because you don't use .Net 5.0 or unsafe code is disabled.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus why all these questions and abuse of the `record` type? Why all these contortions to try and make C# code behave like C, not C++, but *C* code? There's no ambiguity in the docs and a field isn't even a property, so why should it be treated as a record parameter? Properties are part of a type's API, fields are internal implementation. Exposing a field as `public` is essentially a bug

Comment: Besides, what you linked to is the **feature proposal**, not the actual documentation. Things have changed between the proposal and the release, and the whole process was documented in the [csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) repo on GitHub. If you think you've found a discrepancy, post an issue there. I doubt anyone's ever tried to use a `record` this way, so it's quite likely nobody noticed that `unsafe` got away. I wouldn't be surprised if they answered that adding `/unsafe` disabled the compiler checks though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to know what a record is. And it is natural to test what is said in docs. If the docs say it has an error I want to produce that error so that I'm sure I understood correctly. And yes maybe those are proposals and maybe wrong.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus the docs explain what a record is. You aren't testing what's in the docs, you're trying to break the code. Why would anyone try to use not just `unsafe` but an `int*` in a *record* ? People that want mutable classes use `class` or `struct`. As for your exact code, [it looks like the current compiler prevents int*](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoAVwDsoIAzOAAgTgGMB7BFOgJWbZRIG8SdYXQpVadbAGY6AS3IwAVHQAOAbhIBfIA) with an explicit message

Comment: @MinimusHeximus have you actually tried *using* the type instead of trying to break it? Have you read the examples? Are you trying to fit it into another language's model perhaps? Use a record as a C struct?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The docs explain and I have to understand what is explained. So I try to test my understanding and ask if anything goes wrong. I tried to create an unsafe instance field and added `p` and as explained I expect to get an error. But a console core project in VS 2019 compiles it without any errors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to examine and identify `record` with docs and codes. I may never use an unsafe code in a real program. But now I'm learning and examining `record`. The docs say `record`s are immutable by default. I want to understand it. If so, why there are no errors if  mutable?

Comment: [This compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGUCWBbADgGwgAUEB7AcwSm2QBoATEAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKDgA7ZFEgACJAGNSCemIBKEabP4BvfmM1ihI8WwDMYzIJgAqMbgDc/AL78gA===) seems to have different behavior...probably something is wrong with VS.

Comment: No, nothing's wrong with VS. And there's nothing ambiguous to `by default`.

Comment: As for the compiler, the target you should choose is [C# 9: Records](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMYHsEBNkA0uIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUHAHbJSQAEmOuHAShGx5GAb0YcJHFm04UAzBwCWzGACoOABwDcjAL6MgA==) Yes, at some point `unsafe int*` was allowed. In the current development branch, it's not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is ambiguous: a class is not immutable by default and it can be both mutable or immutable. A record is immutable by default and it also can be both mutable or immutable. Now, what the "by default" part means if it has no effects? Does "by default" means "it is recommended to use an immutable record instead of an immutable class"?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So it will have errors in future updates? I thought in .Net 5, C#9.0 is completely implemented.

Comment: `This is ambiguous:` No it's not. `by default` means that something behaves a certain way unless changed. [That's how the phrase is used](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/by-default). This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: So a record is regarded as immutable if it is still not implemented. When implemented, the structure of the record will determine if it is mutable or immutable. "by default" does not seem to have any other meanings.